# LINQ JOIN with a CASE condition in JOIN parameters

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a relatively simple SQL  query that works fine, but cannot figure out how to translate it into LINQ. The trick is a CASE statement in the JOIN, and the CASE references both tables. Here is the SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON
    t2.col1 = t1.col1
AND t2.col2 = CASE
                  WHEN t2.col3 = 1 THEN t1.col2
                  ELSE t1.col3 END
```

As you can see, if my bool in t2.col3 is true, I join  t2.col2 on t1.col2. If the bool is false, I join t2.col2 on t1.col3. In SQL I get the desired result. In LINQ I run into two problems: First, I can't seem to get a ternary working in the join (CASE), and second, I can't get the LINQ join to reference both tables in the join object.

Is there a clean way, or any way to accomplish this SQL query in LINQ?

EDIT

Some of the LINQ I have tried:

```
var result = from t1 in table1
             join t2 in table2
             on new { t1.col1, t2.col3 ? t1.col2 : t1.col3} equals
                new { t2.col2, t2.col2}
```

In this case, the error occurs on the 3rd line in the ternary operation and says `t2 is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'`

Comment: What LINQ code have you tried?

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: It's generally better to user AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I'm not following how that would look in this situation. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: The only error is that `{ t1.col1, t2.col3 ? t1.col2 : t1.col3}` isn't a valid anonymous type declaration. It shouldn't even compile. If you get the reported error it means you're not showing the actual code, which never helps.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ only directly supports [equijoins](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equijoin). If you want to do any other kind of join, you need a cross-join and `where`

```
from t1 in table1
from t2 in table2
where t1.col1 == t2.col1 && ((t2.col3 = 1 && t2.col2 = t1.col2) || (t2.col3 != 1 && t2.col2 = t1.col3))
select ..
```

Answer (score 0):

For such conditions, we need to use `where` clause.

```
 var result = from t1 in table1
              join t2 in table2 on t1.col1 equals t2.col1
              where t2.col2 == (t2.col3 == "1" ? t1.col2 : t1.col3)
              select t2.col2;
```

Or

```
var result2 = from t1 in table1
              from t2 in table2.Where(x=>x.col2 == (x.col3 == "1" ? t1.col2 : t1.col3) &&  x.col1 == t1.col1)
              select t2.col2;
```